# What are these extra IPs shown when using netdiscover?

Tags: virtualbox, kali-linux, nat, metasploit, netdiscover

I've set up a Metaspolitable2 and a Kali Linux machine in VirtualBox. In network settings, I've set up both as a NAT Network, and I've given the NAT Network a DHCP Range of 172.16.10.0/29.

When I do the netdiscover command from the Kali machine (IP - 172.16.10.4), I get the following 4 following IPs discovered. It can be seen in the image attached. I know that the 172.16.10.1 IP is the gateway and the 172.16.10.5 is the Metasploitable2 machine, but what are the other 2 IPs?

Netdiscover output:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within a "NAT" network, VirtualBox's software router always responds to *two* IP addresses: the `.1` address acts as the network's gateway, while the `.2` address is mapped to the host system. Connections from VM guests to 172.16.10.2 will actually reach services on the host's loopback.

The other two IP addresses both have MAC addresses from the OUI used by VirtualBox virtual NICs. (The OUI `08:00:27` used to belong to "Innotek GmbH", which was the original producer of VirtualBox before Oracle bought it.) So if one of them is Metasploitable2, then the other is most likely the Kali VM.

Comment: Thank you. Understood!!

Comment: Hi, I just verified. The 172.16.10.3 IP address is not the Kali. Kali's IP address is 172.16.10.4.

Answer (score 0):

172.16.10.1/2 have the same MAC address, so they are both your router,
publishing two interfaces.

The other two are devices manufactured by
PCS Systemtechnik GmbH company.
As the Metasploitable2 machine is one of them, this virtual machine
might also have two network interfaces.